# Check if FreeMarker #nested directive is empty

Tags: freemarker

I want to output tags around a `<#nested>` directive in a macro, but only if it would actually output something. The actual use case is more complicated, this is just the broken down version.
How do I check for existence of `<#nested>` content?

```
<#macro opt tagname>
    <#if (#nested)??>    <-- what do I need to put here
        <${tagname}>
            <#nested>
        </${tagname}>
    </#if>
</#macro>
```

### Example 1

Template: `<@opt hello />`

Output:   (empty)

### Example 2

Template: `<@opt hello>goodbye</@opt>`

Output: `<hello>goodbye</hello>`

Answer (score 2):

You have to capture the nested content, and then print it if necessary. Like this (this assumes auto-escaping on):

```
<#macro opt tagname>
  <#local nestedContent><#nested></#local>
  <#if nestedContent?has_content>
    <${tagname}>${nestedContent}</${tagname}>
  </#if>
</#macro>
```

Without auto-escaping the `#if` changes to just `<#if nestedContent != ''>`.